# A method was called at an unexpected time. Only one handler for the PrintTaskRequested event may be registered at a time

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Created Frame with UWP to print badge, when performing Print for the first time It was working fine. then trying to print for another badge for other user It was giving error.

Below code is written in side :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    printDoc = new PrintDocument();           
    printDocSource = printDoc.DocumentSource;
    printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;            
    printDoc.GetPreviewPage += GetPreviewPage;
    printDoc.AddPages += AddPages;
    // Register for PrintTaskRequested event         
    printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();            
    printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;
}
```

Tried with [How to disconnect print event handler in uwp printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834268/how-to-disconnect-print-event-handler-in-uwp-printing) still facing the same issue.

Comment: Hard to believe. Can you post a [MRE]? Must be a bug in how you tried it

Comment: Did you read through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) guide?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.